# Solr 4.0 and ResourceLoader: getLines undefined

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solr4

I'm translating to Lucene 4.0 a plug-in developed over Lucene 3.6, but I'm having so much troubles with ResourceLoader.

I've changed the imports related to ResourceLoader from:

```
   import org.apache.solr.common.ResourceLoader;
   import org.apache.solr.util.plugin.ResourceLoaderAware;
```

to:

```
   import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoader;
   import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoaderAware;
```

But at the inform method:

```
public void inform(ResourceLoader loader) {
```

when I try to use the getLines function:

```
List list = loader.getLines("file");
```

I get the following error:

> The method getLines(String) is undefined for the type ResourceLoader

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Lucene 4.0, getLines doesn't have to be invoked as a method from ResourceLoader.

Here you can see an [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/branch_4x/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/StemmerOverrideFilterFactory.java).